# How can i remove the last "-" in the output?

Tags: java, arrays, error-handling, output

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[6];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 90) + 1;
    }

    System.out.println("Dein Lottotipp lautet:");
    sort(array);
    printArray(array);
}

public static void sort(int[] array) {

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        int sortieren = array[i];
        int j = i;
        while (j > 0 && array[j - 1] > sortieren) {
            array[j] = array[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        array[j] = sortieren;

    }

}

public static void printArray(int[] array) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        if (array[i] < array.length - 1) {
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        } else {
            System.out.print(array[i] + "-");
        }

    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

How can i remove the last "-" in the output , im not the best java programmer; The output should be 27-28-37-73-75-81 ,but the output is this 27-28-37-73-75-81-., i need to remove the last - . Can someone please send me the edited code?

Comment: One line method: `System.out.println(Arrays.stream(array).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining("-")));`

Comment: Why did you delete your source code? Your Question no longer makes sense. Voting to close for lack of necessary detail.

Comment: @BasilBourque I rolled the question back; vandalism is vandalism.

Comment: Why have you again deleted your example code, contradicting the rollback by @ElliottFrisch of your previous deletion? Your deletions damage your Question, and make nonsense of the existing Answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not print the last `-`, this line: `if (array[i] < array.length - 1) {` needs to become: `if (i === array.length - 1)`.

At the moment, you are comparing the content of the array with the index you are currently processing. Comparing the content of the array won't do what you need, since you are only interesting in the current iteration number.

Answer (score 1):

## `String.join`

The [Answer by npinti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60994319/642706) is correct, and answers your question specifically.

Here is an alternative solution using the [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.Iterable)) feature. This uses much less code.

```
String result = String.join( "-" , List.of( array ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

**npinti** has identified your issue and you should accept his answer.

However, just as a learning exercise, you could also look at using this common technique, where you print a delimeter for the first `n-1` elements of the array and then just print the last element alone.

```
public static void printArray(int[] array) 
{
  if(array.length == 0) return;

  for(int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++) 
  {
    System.out.print(array[i] + "-");
  }
  System.out.println(array[array.length-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your string and before you output it do

```
String s = //Create your string and save it in s
System.out.println(s.substring(0, s.length()-1));
```

This will cut of the last char of a string.